# Mapping parameters from embedded form within a form MSACESS

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am trying to get a query to update based on a value passed from a combo box within the same form. After I moved the form into a tabbed control box within another form it seems to have broken. I've tried mapping from the outer form to the combo box and still an error to provide parameters into the query.

[image: sub form within tabbed form]

The Outermost form is "workbench"
The tab control is "tabbed_space"
The inner form is "software_list"
The combo box is "cmb_server_selection

I have in the query

```
=[Forms]![workbench]![tabbed_space]![software_list]![cmb_server_selection]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wow that's a serious bug.. that was NOT the title I entered! Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab controls do not affect the "navigation path" of objects, the objects are still directly on their form.

To get objects on a subform, you need `SubformControl.Form!Object`

So it should be

```
=[Forms]![workbench]![software_list].Form![cmb_server_selection]
```

Note: this is easier to debug in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+g) than in the query (the form must be open of course) :

```
? Forms!workbench!software_list.Form!cmb_server_selection
```

Comment: It's crazy - I understood that subform component but when applied to the query it still returns a prompt to populate with data. Not sure how Ctrl+G works it only brings up the VBA pane but nothing that maps from the parent form to the combo list within the sub form. I populated the query with =[Forms]![workbench]![software_list].Form![cmb_server_selection] and no luck

Comment: Not sure where the error was, but once I re-applied the path it worked perfectly. A million thanks for the huge help!!!!